# BluetoothLeScanner.startScan() requires new permissions in Marshmallow?

Tags: android, api, bluetooth, android-6.0-marshmallow

With the Android 6.0 release (API 23), I noticed that `BluetoothLeScanner.startScan()` requires new permissions; `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and/or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. Can anyone please explain the reasoning behind this. Why would a **Bluetooth** `ScanResult` require **Location** permissions?

More information on this change can be found here: [Android 6.0 Changes: Access to hardware identifer](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id)

Thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely due to new BTLE beacon technology such as Apple's iBeacon or Google's own Eddystone spec. These are tools used for microlocation services, and as a result can be used by the application to map out (quite precisely) where you are. Considering that, coarse and fine location permissions seem appropriate.

[Here's some information from Google.](https://developers.google.com/beacons/overview?hl=en)

[Here's some information from Apple.](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/)

[Here's some information from AltBeacon.](http://altbeacon.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This seems a brilliant step by Google. Nevertheless, this has been done in conjunction with the beacon technology launched by Google. There is no technical reason I could find for this. This is similar to the Wifi scanning which also requires device's location. Google seems to be building its database of the beacons and wifi to use it across its range of products. This seems to be capturing the whole data of any application leveraging Beacon Tech.